# FOSRestBundle get properties are different to post properties

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a problem with FOSRestBundle. When I run the get action over the collection I get somethin like this (json format):

```
{"entities":[{"id":1,"main_diagnostic_name":"0000","main_diagnostic_code":"1111","start_date":null,"end_date":null,"patient":{"id":1,"identifier":"3874908","first_name":"Pedro","surname":"Barroso","gender":"M","birth_date":"1972-01-01T00:00:00+0000","photo":null,"communication":"ab","active":true,"nhc":null,"allergy":false,"episodes":[]},"prescriptions":[],"id_bed":1,"separate":null,"special_diet":false,"contagious_diseases":false,"aggressive":false}]}
```

But when I make the post call over the same collection I neet to put the variable names:

```
{"mainDiagnosticName":"XXXX","mainDiagnosticCode":"1111","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"patient":"1","idBed":1,"separate":null,"specialDiet":false,"contagiousDiseases":false,"aggressive":false}
```

**How I can do so that both actions have the same behavior? Why get returns me to underscored parameters?**

This is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace wathever;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Episode
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\EpisodeRepository")
 */
class Episode {

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Prescription" , mappedBy="id")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mainDiagnosticName", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $mainDiagnosticName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mainDiagnosticCode", type="string", length=10)
 */
private $mainDiagnosticCode;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $startDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $endDate;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Patient", inversedBy="patient")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $patient;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Prescription" , mappedBy="episodes")
 */
private $prescriptions;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="idBed", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $idBed;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Beds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bed_id", referencedColumnName="id") */
private $separate;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="specialDiet", type="boolean")
 */
// TODO esto como boleano no debería ser
private $specialDiet;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contagiousDiseases", type="boolean")
 */
// TODO esto como boleano no debería ser
private $contagiousDiseases;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="aggressive", type="boolean")
 */
private $aggressive;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set mainDiagnosticName
 *
 * @param string $mainDiagnosticName
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setMainDiagnosticName($mainDiagnosticName) {
    $this->mainDiagnosticName = $mainDiagnosticName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mainDiagnosticName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getMainDiagnosticName() {
    return $this->mainDiagnosticName;
}

/**
 * Set mainDiagnosticCode
 *
 * @param string $mainDiagnosticCode
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setMainDiagnosticCode($mainDiagnosticCode) {
    $this->mainDiagnosticCode = $mainDiagnosticCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mainDiagnosticCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getMainDiagnosticCode() {
    return $this->mainDiagnosticCode;
}

/**
 * Set startDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $startDate
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setStartDate($startDate) {
    $this->startDate = $startDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getStartDate() {
    return $this->startDate;
}

/**
 * Set endDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $endDate
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setEndDate($endDate) {
    $this->endDate = $endDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEndDate() {
    return $this->endDate;
}

/**
 * Set patient
 *
 * @param integer $patient
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setIdPatient($idPatient) {
    $this->patient = $patient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get patient
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPatient() {
    return $this->patient;
}

/**
 * Set idBed
 *
 * @param integer $idBed
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setIdBed($idBed) {
    $this->idBed = $idBed;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idBed
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdBed() {
    return $this->idBed;
}

/**
 * Set separate
 *
 * @param boolean $separate
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setSeparate($separate) {
    $this->separate = $separate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get separate
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getSeparate() {
    return $this->separate;
}

/**
 * Set specialDiet
 *
 * @param boolean $specialDiet
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setSpecialDiet($specialDiet) {
    $this->specialDiet = $specialDiet;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get specialDiet
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getSpecialDiet() {
    return $this->specialDiet;
}

/**
 * Set contagiousDiseases
 *
 * @param boolean $contagiousDiseases
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setContagiousDiseases($contagiousDiseases) {
    $this->contagiousDiseases = $contagiousDiseases;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get contagiousDiseases
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getContagiousDiseases() {
    return $this->contagiousDiseases;
}

/**
 * Set aggressive
 *
 * @param boolean $aggressive
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setAggressive($aggressive) {
    $this->aggressive = $aggressive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get aggressive
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getAggressive() {
    return $this->aggressive;
}

/**
 * Set patient
 *
 * @param \Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Patient $patient
 * @return Episode
 */
public function setPatient(\Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Patient $patient = null) {
    $this->patient = $patient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct($object = null) {
    $this->prescriptions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->patient = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($object){
        $this->setParameters($object);
    }
}

public function setParameters($object){

    $vars = get_object_vars($object)
            ;
            foreach ($vars as $v){

call_user_func('set'.$v, $object->get($v));
            }

    return $this;
}


 /**
 * Add prescriptions
 *
 * @param \Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Prescription $prescriptions
 * @return Episode
 */
public function addPrescription(\Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Prescription $prescriptions) {
    $this->prescriptions[] = $prescriptions;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove prescriptions
 *
 * @param \Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Prescription $prescriptions
 */
public function removePrescription(\Strim\NursingBundle\Entity\Prescription $prescriptions) {
    $this->prescriptions->removeElement($prescriptions);
}

/**
 * Get prescriptions
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPrescriptions() {
    return $this->prescriptions;
}

}
```

This is my cgetAction:

```
/**
 * Collection get action
 * @var Request $request
 * @return array
 * @Rest\View()
 */
public function cgetAction(Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Episode')->findAll();
    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

And my POST action:

```
/**
 * Collection post action -> Crear un elemento de la colección
 * @var Request $request
 * @return View|array
 * @Rest\View()
 */
public function cpostAction(Request $request) {
      $entity = new Episode();
      $form = $this->createForm(new EpisodeType(), $entity);

      $form->bind($request);
 if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response($request, 201);
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form,
    );
}
```

Comment: Nobody knows?I've seen that in JMSSerializerBundle, but I'm looking for a better solution: @SerializedName¶
This annotation can be defined on a property to define the serialized name for a property. If this is not defined, the property will be translated from camel-case to a lower-cased underscored name, e.g. camelCase -> camel_case.

Comment: See this link: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/33 however it is not clear exactly how to implement this pass through naming strategy as part of FOSRest.. I'm looking into this at the moment because yeah it is a pain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the same json format as the "post" action you have to use a [FOSRestBundle View](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md):

here an excerpt on how your cgetAction should look like:

```
/**
* Collection get action
* @var Request $request
* @return array
* @Rest\View()
*/
public function cgetAction(Request $request) {
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Episode')->findAll();

   //set the view:
   $view = View::create();
   $handler = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler');
   $view->setData($entity);

   return $view;
 }
```

Remember to put in your "use" statement `use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;` to be able to user FosRestBungle view handler.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** Only after submitting this post, I have noticed, that it'll be much easier for my usecase to just use the IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy delivered with JMSSerializer, instead of the overriding and de-configuring method described below. What remains, thus, is simply

```
# file: app/config.yml
parameters:
    jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy
```

---

It might help you to override the JMSSerializer's default camel case naming strategy. I have extended the CamelCaseNamingStrategy as follows

```
// File: MyName/MyBundle/Serializer/CamelCaseNamingStrategy.php
namespace MyName\MyBundle\Serializer;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata;

class CamelCaseNamingStrategy extends \JMS\Serializer\Naming\CamelCaseNamingStrategy
{
    public function translateName(PropertyMetadata $property)
    {
        return lcfirst(parent::translateName($property));
    }
}
```

Then, you can configure JMSSerializerBundle to use this class instead of the original one

```
# file: app/config.yml
parameters:
    jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: MyName\MyBundle\Serializer\CamelCaseNamingStrategy
```

Finally, you need to disable the lower-casing and seperator-inserting JMSSerializer would usually do.

```
# still in app/config.yml
jms_serializer:
    property_naming:
        separator:
        lower_case: false
```

Comment: nice ! I don't really understand why properties names are underscorized and so not left as is *by default*

Comment: Actually it's not easier because `IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy` doesn't consider your configuration types and stuff